# Java Spring Hibernate SQL select with order by causes in DB2 big performance impact

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2

I have table T_LOG, which has a few millions of row. Hibernate `3.6.10.Final` using Detached Criteria produces inefficient SQL query, which causes big performance impact.

Simplified sample:

```
    select temp.* from ( select row_number() over(order by a.dateTime asc) as rownumber, a.dateTime, a.*
from T_LOG a order by a.dateTime asc) as temp where rownumber <= 75;
```

The problem is `order by a.dateTime asc` (2), which is redundant, because whole work is doing by first clause `row_number() over(order by a.dateTime asc)` (1).
This additional second `order by` clause causes about 1000 times worse result, than the same one without it's.
For example, the statement above needs more than 10 minutes on 25 millions rows, but this simplified statement:

```
    select temp.* from ( select row_number() over(order by a.dateTime asc) as
 rownumber, a.dateTime, a.* from T_LOG a) as temp where rownumber <= 75;
```

Takes only 0.1 second. The result set is the same. The column `dateTime` is indexed non-unique index.

In Java detached Criteria (simplified) looks like this:

```
            DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Log.class);
...
            crit.addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.asc("dateTime"));

// Used for pagination      
List<Log> logs = logRepository.findByCriteria(crit, from, count);
```

How can I reduce the SQL statement in detached criteria to avoid performance impact?

Sample of good cost:

[image: Proper cost of SQL]

And bed cost:

[image: Very bad cost of SQL]

Comment: Have you looked at the explain plan for the two queries. I'm would be surprised if  Db2 is not removing the redundant `ORDER BY` in the first example.

Comment: I added a sample explain plan. The second image demonstrates how the optimizer will include a filter that causes a performance drop.

Comment: Might be best raising a case with IBM Support, or trying a newer version of Db2 if you are not on a recent release. The optimizer will often remove redundant clauses, but not in every case, so if this is one that is not removed by the optimizer you might be stuck with needing to alter the SQL yourself